# Any way to provide reason to a disabled suite in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, test-suite

Currently, we can give reason to pending spec using `pend()` function this way -

```
xit("pending spec", function(){
    //Skipped spec
}).pend("This is a reason");
```

Output of the above function would be -

```
Sample Test: pending spec
This is a reason
Executed 1 of 1 specs (1 PENDING)
```

Now, how to get the same reason for the disabled suites?

```
xdescribe('Disabled suite' , function(){
    it('example spec', function(){
        //example
    });
}).pend("This is a reason");
```

Output of the above disabled suite is -

```
No reason given
```

and remains the same even if I use `pend()` function. Thanks!

Comment: The pending message on a suite is not yet supported. See by yourself: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/Suite.js#L45

Comment: Thanks @FlorentB. I was hoping to see some way I can make this happen. I know `pend()` doesn't work, but is there any other way that we can do it? Simply showing "No reason given" doesn't make sense without adding a customization feature to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pending message is not implemented on a suite, but you could override the `pend` method to make it write the message on each spec:

```
jasmine.Suite.prototype.pend = function(message){
    this.markedPending = true;
    this.children.forEach(spec => spec.pend(message));
};
```

Usage:

```
xdescribe('Suite', function() {


}).pend("Feature not yet implemented");
```

Source code for `Suite.js`:

https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/Suite.js#L45

Comment: cool, I forgot that I could override the implementation.. Thanks!